# Codeigniter active record : how to read the joined table

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

i have some table, and the relationship goes like this

[image: img]

and i want to get all the record of those 2 tables. so i use this query in my model

```
 $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material.*,ms_Material_Jasa.*');
    $this->db->join('ms_Material_Jasa', 'ms_Kategori_Material.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa = ms_Material_Jasa.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    $table = $this->db->get();
    return $table;
```

and then i got error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '*, `ms_Material_Jasa`.*) JOIN `ms_Material_Jasa` ON `ms_Kategori_Material`.`Kode' at line 2

SELECT * FROM (`ms_Kategori_Material`.*, `ms_Material_Jasa`.*) JOIN `ms_Material_Jasa` ON `ms_Kategori_Material`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` = `ms_Material_Jasa`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa`
```

why do i can't read the needed table ?

Comment: `$this->db->join('ms_Material_Jasa', 'ms_Kategori_Material.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa = ms_Material_Jasa.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa','left');`

Comment: @RPM it returns error like this `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN `ms_Material_Jasa` ON `ms_Kategori_Material`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_J' at line 2`

Answer (score 1):

in your from, there shouldnt be a .*,

i.e

```
    $this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material','ms_Material_Jasa');
```

and if your adding the table to join, no need to add it to from.

so it becomes

```
 $this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material');
 $this->db->join('ms_Material_Jasa','....');
```

final query:

```
 $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material');
    $this->db->join('ms_Material_Jasa', 'ms_Kategori_Material.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa = ms_Material_Jasa.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa');
    $result = $this->db->get();

    $table = $this->db->get();
    return $table;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material'); // full table name
$this->db->join('ms_Material_Jasa', 'ms_Kategori_Material.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa = ms_Material_Jasa.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa');

$result = $this->db->get();
//print_r($this->db->last_query()); display raw sql

$print_r($result->result_array());
```

Read more @ [http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html](http://codeigniter.com/user%5fguide/database/active%5frecord.html)

Comment: i need to use the entire record of those 2 table when i use this `$this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material','ms_Material_Jasa');` it doesn't return the `Kode_Material_Jasa` values

Comment: Take a look at $this->db->join(); on codeigniter site http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html. Also do a print_r($this->db->last_query()); and look at what the resulting query is.

Comment: Are any of the column names the same in both tables?

Comment: yes, its `Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` columns ,when i use `print_r($this->db->last_query());` it shows blank white screen

Comment: Your query is only miss that 'Kode_Material_Jasa` record, and the other else seems fine

Answer (score 0):

You may try this (to join and select fields from both tables)

```
$this->db->select('ms_Kategori_Material.*, ms_Material_Jasa.*');
$this->db->from('ms_Kategori_Material');
$this->db->from('ms_Material_Jasa');
$this->db->join('ms_Material_Jasa', 'ms_Kategori_Material.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa = ms_Material_Jasa.Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa');
$table = $this->db->get();
return $table->result();
```

Comment: it returns error `Not unique table/alias: 'ms_mat'

SELECT `ms_kat`.*, `ms_mat`.* FROM (`ms_Kategori_Material` ms_kat, `ms_Material_Jasa` ms_mat) JOIN `ms_mat` ON `ms_kat`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` = `ms_mat`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa``

Comment: still receiving the same error, it said `Not unique table/alias: 'ms_Material_Jasa'

SELECT `ms_Kategori_Material`.*, `ms_Material_Jasa`.* FROM (`ms_Kategori_Material`, `ms_Material_Jasa`) JOIN `ms_Material_Jasa` ON `ms_Kategori_Material`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa` = `ms_Material_Jasa`.`Kode_Kategori_Material_Jasa``